# Apache server log error. AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET, etc

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, error-handling

I checked the server log recently, there are so many error types.

**1 .  AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /../../terms HTTP/1.1 .**

This kind of error is the most common one, our website is on Wordpress. This page is on www.MYSITENAME.com/terms.   I check most of the pages, and checked the links, all of them did not cause this invalid Request.

But if I use postman, type the URL directly, like: www.MYSITENAME.com/../terms, this would cause the error and also it would be catched and logged.

Any idea about this error? I search it on google, someone said it is the problem from the .htaccess file, but I dont really understand it.

**2. PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): (00000/0):  in /var/www/www.MYSITENAME.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2007**

I have no idea about this one.

**3. PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 20971520) (tried to allocate 77824 bytes)**

**4. PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=22936 in /var/www/www.MYSITENAME.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2007**

**5.  PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/www.MYSITENAME.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-cerber/common.php on line 1968**

**6.  PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/www.MYSITENAME.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-cerber/common.php on line 2017**

Any idea about Any error?
Thanks.

Comment: _“Any idea about Any error?”_ - if you have no clue what they _mean_ at all, then please start by researching them. (Talking about number 2 - 6 here.)

Comment: Yep, I just want to solve it one by one, just record all problem first. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the first error:[ AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /../../terms HTTP/1.1 .], I found out where was going wrong. On my site, sitting on wordpress and also editting from wordpress, we used the relative URL before. Now we fix it to the absolute one.

I have searched for some relevant questions, someone said this kind of problem is caused by crawler program, but others said .htaccess leads the problem.   But I do recommend just go through your own code about the URL parts first